# Checking for an end_time < Time.now in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Checking for an end_time < Time.now in scope.

I have a method which defines an 'ends_at' time and checks if it's 'over':

```
def end_time
  created_at + ends_at.day
end

def over?
  end_time < Time.now
end
```

I fear that my solution is not quite correct:

```
def self.ended
  Campaign.all.select {|c| c.over? == true}
end
```

Comment: What does `ends_at.day` do?

Comment: @zeantsoi this is the number of days that the user entered. (type integer)

Comment: Can you confirm that `end_time` returns a `Time` object?

Comment: @zeantsoi Yes, I confirm.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Check whether all campaigns have ended?

Comment: @zeantsoi I need to find campaigns which ended.

Comment: Instead of `Campaign.all.select {|c| c.over? == true}`, have you tried `Campaign.where(over?: true)`?

Comment: @zeantsoi yes.  `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column campaigns.over? does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" WHERE "campaigns"."ov...`

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your solution you are getting **all** campaings from database and then see which one check the condition, this is not a good idea...
Also, why don't you store the date of end in database? That should be easier.

Try something like this:

```
 def self.ended
   Campaign.where(created_at > ?, Time.now - ends_at.day)
 end
```

Comment: `undefined local variable or method 'end_time'`

Comment: Well,I dont know where ends_at from your question came front, because you are using it in the method end_time. It is a field from database or what?

Comment: Yes, this field from the database

Comment: Inside which class is the method self.ended? If it is Campaign model try self.ends_at.day . To work,the method  self.ended should be inside Campaign model and ends_at should be an attribute of Campaign.